# Difference two attenuation constant

Tags: attenuation

When finding parameters for electromagnetic waves and transmission lines, we can find various characteristics including attenuation and characteristic impedance.
\$\alpha\$ is attenuation constant.

1-With \$\alpha\$ as an attenuation constant for propagation we can determine:

\$ \displaystyle \alpha = \frac{1}{R_0}(R+G|Z_0|^2)\$

2-We can also determine the characteristic impedance.after that we can determine 
\$\alpha\$ for distortionless lines or low-loss lines from these equations:

\$ \displaystyle Z_0= \sqrt{\frac{R+j\omega L}{G+j\omega C}} = R_0 + jX_0 \$

\$ \displaystyle\ \gamma = \sqrt{(R+jwL)(G+j\omega C)}\$

How can we prove that the attenuation constant, \$\alpha\$ in first equation, is equal to the  \$\alpha\$ that we can determine from second equations??

Comment: Start by using mathjax to arrange your formulas so that they are unambiguous. Next wait for an answer but in the meantime do some more googling - there are plenty of resources out there. Also note that the term radical is not favoured particularly - try using square root

Answer (score 0):

Although not a proof, this answers the practical significance.

\$10log(α) ≈10log( \dfrac{R}{2Z_0} + \dfrac{GZ_0}{2})\$ becomes the attenuation in dB per unit length for low loss cables for lower RF bands.

To make it more accurate, dielectric constant and thus C reduces slightly in the GHz region and G rises thus loss tangent degradation is a function of dielectric where Teflon is better and air core with foam even better.  The skin effects increase R with rising f and thus the real qualities of coax , striplines become more difficult and critical costs($) rise with bandwidth that spans many decades in the microwave bands.

\$\gamma = \sqrt{(R+jwL)(G+j\omega C)} \$ is the propagation phaseshift of frequency  per unit length which are given by R,G,L,C per unit length.

Both your equations and these are derived from Telegrapher’s equation and Heaviside’s transmission model.